# Do send raw transactions consume extra gas as opposed to a send transaction

Tags: transactions, gas, infura, raw-transaction

I would assume the portion of verifying the signature consumes gas. I'm asking this because it seems infura does not handle signed transactions and I have a getBalance Call that is failing.

I would assume getBalance, firstly, is a call so this isn't relevant.
Irrespective, Do raw transactions consume extra gas opposed to a regular transaction?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "raw transaction" and "regular transaction"?

Comment: @smarx: I assume he/she mean `sendSignedTransaction` vs `sendTransaction` (which relies on the fact that the account specified at the `from` field is unlocked on the node). Of course, the answer is that the latter does not consume more gas, and the only difference being that your node uses your unlocked account in order to sign it instead of you signing it. And so the difference between them is reflected in the security aspect, not in the gas-cost aspect (where *security* = your willingness to maintain a node which stores your unlocked account).

Comment: @goodvibration Those were the calls i meant. I didn't know you could leave an account unlocked on the node. Still, Infura doesn't support sendTransaction, you have to manage the keys on your side and send signed transaction using sendRawTransaction. So if the account was 'unlocked' why would they require a signed transaction post the unlocking.

Comment: When you "unlock" an account on your own Ethereum node (e.g. Geth or Parity running on your computer), it means that node knows the private key for that account and will sign transactions with it. Infura doesn't know your private key, so it can't sign anything for you.

Comment: Ethereum itself doesn't have any such thing as a "raw transaction" or "regular transaction". All transactions are signed with a private key, and that's how the system knows who sent the transaction.

Comment: "So if the account was 'unlocked' why would they require a signed transaction post the unlocking?" - I think you've answered your own question, i.e., the account **wasn't** unlocked.

Comment: it would cost the same